# Replace all multispace characters with a single space EXCEPT the newline character

Tags: php, regex

The title is self explanatory.

Currently I use `preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$row['message']);` but this removes newline characters as well, but I want to preserve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double negated class, and negate `\n`. This is the perfect case to use [regex-negation](/questions/tagged/regex-negation)!

```
preg_replace('/[^\S\n]+/', ' ', $row['message']);
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/yL9qK2/2).

Comment: @AvinashRaj That is correct! Or you can use `[[:blank:]]+`